# Resize reCAPTCHA image selection box

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I have a form inside a modal and has reCAPTCHA  in it. But when I click the `I am not robot` button, the box where you select images goes up to high in the browser, high enough that i can't select anyting.

[image]

Attached is the screen shot, I viewed the css inside it and seems like this is auto genereted by google? Is there anyway to fix this or override via css?

I tried searching net but all I see is just resizing the reCAPTCHA box not the image selection box

My code is this, this is inside a modal body tag:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" ></div>
```

My js:

```
var CaptchaCallback = function(){
$('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
    grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : 'mycode'});
    console.log("Re-capcha loaded");
});
 };
```

Comment: can you provide some code snippet along with description

Comment: @a1626 updated my post

Comment: As i've not worked on `recaptcha` before it would be really helpful if you can provide me code from which i can reproduce the issue. `fiddle` or `pen` will also do.

Comment: ignore the above comment, but can you provide me enough code so that i can reproduce your problem, things like where have you placed you `recaptcha` div tag and related css

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine with all my popups which are having Google Recaptcha.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" 
     style="transform:scale(0.77);
     -webkit-transform:scale(0.70);
     transform-origin:4% 0 ;
     -webkit-transform-origin:7% 0;
     "data-sitekey="Your Site Key">
</div>
```

Generally Recaptcha screen (with Images) starts exactly next to Recaptcha checkbox.
I also tested your code with my popups and it worked well. There might be problem with your popup css. Have a look on it and then give it a try.